# Survey in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, survey

I really need some help with this survey. I want to insert it into phpmyadmin. I'm studying and i need this for a project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
<form action="action.php" method="get">
    <h1>KÆLEDYR</h1>
    <h3>Oplysninger om dig</h3>
    Navn:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Navn"><br><br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="navn@gmail.com"><br><br>
    Køn:<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Mand<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Kvinde<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Ved ikke<br><br>
    Alder:
    <input type="number" name="age" value="ex.20"><br><br>

    <h3>Har du kæledyr?</h3>
    Har du kæledyr?:<br>
    <input type="radio" name="yes" value="yes" checked>Ja<br>
    <input type="radio" name="no" value="no">Nej<br><br>

    Hvis ja, hvor mange har du?:
    <input type="number" name="pet-number" value="ex.20"><br><br>

    Hvilke kældedyr har du?:
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal1" value="Hund">Hund
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal2" value="Kat">Kat
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal3" value="Reptil">Reptil
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal4" value="Fugl">Fugl
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal5" value="Fisk">Fisk
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal6" value="Hest">Hest
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal6" value="andet">Andet  
    <br><br>

    Kældedyrs quiz: 
    <br>
    En dalmatiner er stribet?:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="true" value="true" checked>Sandt<br>
    <input type="radio" name="false" value="false">Falsk<br><br>
    <br>
    En hest har 5 ben:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="true" value="true" checked>Sandt<br>
    <input type="radio" name="false" value="false">Falsk<br><br>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My action.php looks like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
/*
File: action.php
Purpose: INSERT INTO ...
*/

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","survey"); // creates the object
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error; // if error messages
}

echo "You're connected to the database via: " 
. $mysqli->host_info 
. "\n";



    if($_GET) { 
    /*          
        $fn = $_GET['firstName'];
        $ln = $_GET['lastName'];    

        // format the sql
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `sakila`.`actor` (`actor_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `last_update`) VALUES (NULL, '" 
        . $fn 
        . "', '" 
        . $ln 
        . "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
        */          
        // INSERT
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `person` (`name`, '".$_GET['name']."')";
        echo $_GET["name"];


        $insert = $mysqli->query($sql); 

        echo "<p>et svar her ....</p>";
        echo $sql;

    }
    else {
        echo "<p>Error: Use the form please. No GET got.</p>";
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

How do i proceed and get my survey into the database?

Comment: so whats the problem? you seem to be on the right path from the code youve posted.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The code looks alright to me.

Comment: Your problem is the SQL request =>  INSERT INTO (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2) :)

Comment: Well i think i am on the right path but i can't seem to figure out how to get my survey into the database.

Comment: just execute select command and get all survey data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inserting the data in the wrong way. Your query should be like this:

```
//FOR SINGLE ITEM
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `person` (`name`) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."')";
//FOR MULTIPLE ITEMS
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `person` (`name`,`email`,`gender`) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['gender']."')";
```

> See [PHP Insert Data Into MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Comment: Thanks. So how do i get the email into the database?

I thought that it would be like this:
$sql = "INSERT INTO `person` (`name`) VALUES('".$_POST['name']."'(`email`) VALUES('".$_POST['email']."'(`gender`) VALUES('".$_POST['gender']."')";

Comment: @SørenVigsøMorthorst I've updated the answer. For multiple items, the format is still the same, you just need to put a comma `,` as a divider.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So normally you would make different tabels for different information? I have a table for persons, but the for the info like maybe their interests or so. Would you make a new table for that?

Comment: @SørenVigsøMorthorst What do you mean about make a new table? Creating another table in the database or just another `INSERT` statement for another table?

Comment: Well i'm not that much into this so i am just seeking some advice. It's the database i mean. Would you make another table for some other information?

Comment: @SørenVigsøMorthorst In a single query statement, you can use (1) or more tables depending on your needs. Here are some tutorial pages that you can use for references [Tutorial1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax.html), [Tutorial2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/), and [Tutorial3](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/). Just pick some topics you needed right there at the sidebar menu.

Answer (score 3):

Try considering following things

1. Change sql query.

   ```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `person` (`name`) VALUES('".$_GET['name']."')";
   ```
2. Change method to `POST` if `GET` is not necessary, It keeps your url clean and your data hidden

   ```
   <form action="action.php" method="post">
   ```
3. Add name and value to submit button.

   ```
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="true">
   ```
4. Check with isset function replace `if($_GET) {` to

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   ```

Comment: You got a good eyesight! :D

Comment: 5. If your survey is user input, remove the value inside the input tag. `<input type="text" name="name">`

Comment: Phpmyadmin is not a database